# Erro de formatação de dados

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, helper

Bem é o seguinte.

eu vou buscar certos textos a base de dados, para depois os listar em web, e quando o faço, os acentos ficam todos uns quadrados e por assim em diante.
Mas quando eu escrevo no proprio codigo com acentos e tal, fica tudo normal.
E eu estou a usar a meta tag e mesmo assim nada.

Qual é o problema ?

Answer (score 0):

O problema esta na codificação entre o código escrito e o banco de dados. Você pode seguir alguns passos para resolver, vou exemplificar com UTF-8:

Primeiro verifique se sua IDE esta codificando em UTF-8. No caso do Eclipse está no **Edit** >> **Set Encoding** >> **Troque por UTF-8**.

Segundo certifique que seu navegador entenda que você esta utilizando UTF-8:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" >
```

Verifique se seu banco esta codificado para UTF-8:

> MySQL

```
CREATE DATABASE nome_bd CHARACTER SET UTF8;
```

E que seu acesso ao banco de dados esteja na mesma codificação.

> MySQL (PDO):

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=world;charset=utf8";
$opcoes = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8'
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $senha, $opcoes);
```

> MySQLi:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8'));
```

Comment: Eu tentei meter o chaset no php e mesmo assim não fez nada. não entendi foi a parte da base de dados. ela já esta criada, mas tenho que a criar de novo ?

Comment: Não é necessário recriar o banco, só vai te custar um pouco mais de trabalho.

Answer (score 0):

Como você já criou o banco de dados você terá um trabalho um pouco maior, faça o seguinte:

> Alterar a codificação do banco de dados:

```
ALTER DATABASE <nome_do_banco> CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

> Alterar a codificação das tabelas:

```
ALTER TABLE <nome_da_tabela> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

> Alterar a codificação das colunas:

```
ALTER TABLE <nome_da_tabela> MODIFY <nome_da_coluna> <VARCHAR(255)> CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Ou você pode executar essas queries a baixo para facilitar seu trabalho tendo que percorrer todo o banco.**

```
SELECT DISTINCT concat('ALTER DATABASE ', TABLE_SCHEMA, ' CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;')
from information_schema.tables
where TABLE_SCHEMA like  'database_name';
```

--

```
SELECT concat('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', table_name, ' CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;')
from information_schema.tables
where TABLE_SCHEMA like 'database_name';
```

--

```
SELECT concat('ALTER TABLE ', t1.TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', t1.table_name, ' MODIFY ', t1.column_name, ' ', t1.data_type , '(' , CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH , ')' , ' CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;')
from information_schema.columns t1
where t1.TABLE_SCHEMA like 'database_name' and CHARACTER_SET_NAME = ‘old_charset_name';
```

Comment: Já resolvi, Obrigado Thiago

Comment: Compartilhe conosco como você conseguiu resolver o problema. Vai ser útil para os próximos.